# Jplayer audio not working in Linux chrome

Tags: php, javascript, linux, jplayer

I am using jplayer.js to play the song in my site. In windows it was working perfectly in all browsers. But in Linux system, the songs doesn't play in chrome browser.Anyone help me to sort out this issue. I have configured the jplayer displayed in the below details..

```
swfPath : "js",
supplied : "mp3",
wmode : "window"
```

Comment: Check that if actual [demo](http://www.proeventdj.com/jplayer/demos/pedj-audio.htm) of jPlayer is working or not.

Comment: @Rikesh The actual jplayer demo also not working

Comment: So it is clear that it is not your code problem. There must be issue of some missing codecs for your chrome browser to support mp3. Hope this work `sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra`. Or install latest stable version of chrome & check again.